# react-vis: How to format ISO dates

Tags: reactjs, react-vis

I have a live `time-series` data connected to a front-end react-vis XY plot. The data is fed as a `JSON` by a `python Flask Server`. The `JSON` contains `date` in `iso format`; Something like `2019-11-21T00:00:00.000Z`.

I am able to display the `time-series` data on the chart; however, the `x-axis` values show up as `ISO format`.

How can I display the dates as `MM/DD/YYYY` format on the `x-axis` of a `react-vis` XY plot? I am already using `xType="ordinal"` attribute of the XY plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your XAxis use tickFormat. So it will be something like this:

```
<XAxis
  tickFormat={value => moment(value).format('DD/MM/YYYY')}
  tickValues={yourValuesFromJson || []}
/>
```

Comment: Awesome! that did it.